# What IDE/editors provide multi-selection editing capabilities? (like Sublime Text does)

Tags: ide, editor, multi-select, sublimetext

The main feature of [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) that makes it my editor of choice for programming (and anything else really) is [multi-selection search and edit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2SVJa2EGIw). It's like search-and-replace-on-steroids. Once you get used to, it's really hard to go back to not using it.

I did some research myself and couldn't find a single other editor that offers it as powerfully. Some even let you create several cursors but lack the searching bit (just found out that [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does that).

So I'd like to ask for this community's help: do you know of another programming editor that provide multi-selection search and editing in a **similar level** as Sublime does?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not content with Sublime Text 2?  Why not just stick with it?

Comment: I used to use Eclipse which is a full blown IDE before and I'm still missing features Sublime doesn't offer off the shelf (and probably never will given it's completely different focus).

Comment: hmm... I used to use Eclipse for Java, then when I switched to Sublime Text I wasn't worried because all the features I needed, I could make with a python plugin.  For example: https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions. But to each their own.  Also, I assume you're on windows (since you mentioned Notepad++) but I believe Textmate 2 offers improved multiple cursor support.

Comment: @BoundinCode the main reason most people just like my colleaques dont swap to ST2 like me, is that they want the object reference / go to function - I know there are some plugins for that, but most of them lose either performance or complete track. And we are just working on a 375.000 lines project. Therefore, these things are kind of essential. I am cool without it but for many thats the main killing point.

Answer (score 2):

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/site/blog/2012/08/be-an-armenian-warrior-with-block-selection-on-steroids/) does this.

Disclaimer: I work there.

Comment: i am having a hard time finding this feature in cloud 9 can you tell me how can I select multiple and edit at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

vim seems to have support for that via plugins. See a related question on SO: [Multiple selections in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608204/multiple-selections-in-vim)

Answer (score 1):

More recently [jetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com) began adding "Sublime Text style multi selection" to their line of IDEs. I know  IntelliJ and Pycharm already have it.

Answer (score 0):

gedit 3 has a plugin which looks similar: http://codetree.com.au/projects/imitation/

Answer (score 0):

After switching from Sublime Text 2 to gedit, I've written a plugin that's much closer to Sublime's version of multiple cursors than [imitation](http://codetree.com.au/projects/imitation/). I've tested the plugin on versions 3.4 and 3.12. You can find it here:

https://github.com/jessecrossen/Gedit-MultiCursor

I don't think it's 100% perfect yet, so I'd be really glad to hear of any edge cases people run across so I can continue to improve it. I've also implemented something like gedit's Command-R functionality with [this plugin](https://github.com/jessecrossen/Gedit-FunctionFinder).

Those were pretty much the only two features I missed from Sublime, but then again I don't tend to use the deep features of any editor, so as to preserve my independence ;). The quick-open functionality is not as good as Sublime's "Goto Anything", but on the other hand you get usable integration with remote file systems mounted on FUSE, gvfs or similar, whereas [Sublime tends to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528182/sublime-text-2-is-sluggish-during-work-over-sshfs) because it's recursively indexing every file.

Comment: Just a note that file **content** indexing in ST can be disabled by setting the `index_files` option to `false`. I did that when working with a project mapped through sshfs. It still maps all included file names/paths though.

Comment: @Chuim Yes, indexing the names/paths is exactly the problem I had. With a large project, Sublime's automatic tree traversal causes manual drill-down to be unusably slow for a significant amount of time. The best thing IMO would be some way to mark or detect remote file systems and reduce features accordingly, but I understand that this would add significant configuration complexity.