# add the next occurrence of the current word to the selection in VIM

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I just switch from Sublime text to MacVim. One useful shortcut I loved in sublime is cmd+D which adds the next occurrence of the current word to the selection.
Is there any way I can get the equivalent in VIM?

Many thanks

Comment: No quick and clean way to do this in stock vim. I switched to using vim plugin within vscode and this works well for me to solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76358638/2826818

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively, but you can look if the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) has this feature.

Here is a related stackoverflow question: [Multiple selections in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608204/multiple-selections-in-vim).

If you know that you want to select and modify all occurrences of the current word under the cursor, press `*` to select it and in command-mode execute:

```
%s//replacement
```

Otherwise, if you don't want the replacement to happen in the whole file, select the word with `*`, select a few lines in visual mode and in command-mode execute:

```
s//replacement
```