# Place multiple cursors with the same word prefix in VS code vim plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In the vscode vim plugin, I use `gb` to select multiple words. I have four functions starting with `handle` but they are not exactly the same word.  How can I put multi cursor for selecting them? Thanks in advance!

```
  handleSearchTermOnChange 
  handleActivateSearch 
  handleDeactivateSearch
  handleSearchQuery
```

Comment: Vim doesn't have a built-in `gb` command that does what you describe and it doesn't have "multi cursor" either. Are you sure you are using Vim?

Comment: @romainl I use the vscode vim plugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With my understanding (in VsCodeVim) you can.

1. `v`
2. cover the desired word/prefix (in your case handle)
3. `gb` as many times desired to choose all the instances you want.
4. Then do whatever you like whit the chosen words.

Happy shortcut coding.

Comment: Just forgot the visual mode select. Thanks!

Comment: @tcf01 a small improvement: you can also change step 3 to `ctrl+shift+L` (which is command for "Select All Matches") if you know you want to select all occurrences. This way you can leave unnecessary `gb` clicks out and do the same thing even faster.

Comment: To add on the selection hit `shift+a`

Comment: ctrl-shift-L doesn't work for me, but ctrl-d (cmd-d) does this as well. I tried to give some more detail on step 4 as well in below answer

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on this a bit more, there is multi cursor support with the below method:

1. With cursor in desired location enter visual mode. Can do this with either CMD-D/CTRL-D (Mac/other platforms) or regular vim shortcut with the V key

[image]

2. Select text with arrow/navigation keys.

[image]

3. Now hit CMD-D/CTRL-D to select the next occurrence and repeat as needed to select more. Similarly gb can also be used as stated in Hessuew's answer.

[image]

4. Now regular vim commands in visual mode can be used (replace, delete, etc.) or you can enter insert mode with multiple cursors by hitting: shift+i or shift+a (shown below for shift+a)

[image]